# How to display all wishlist items in wishlist sidebar

Tags: magento2, wishlist

i Want to display all wish-list items in the sidebar?

Currently only last added three items are showing up.

I wanted to display all items in current wishlist selection.

What should I change in this file:

> vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/sidebar.phtml

[image]

Comment: did you get the solution ?

Comment: https://nwdthemes.com/2019/08/23/magento-2-working-with-wishlist/#magento2_wishlist_1

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by plugin or overwrite of `**Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist**`. I will cover pluginize `**getSectionData**` for achieving this.

> VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist">
        <plugin name="customer_data_wishlist" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php

```
> namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Wishlist\CustomerData;


class Wishlist
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $wishlistHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
     */
    protected $imageHelperFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface
     */
    protected $view;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar
     */
    protected $block;

    /**
     * Wishlist constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view
    ) {
        $this->wishlistHelper = $wishlistHelper;
        $this->imageHelperFactory = $imageHelperFactory;
        $this->block = $block;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function aroundGetSectionData(
        \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $counter = $this->getCounter();
        return [
            'counter' => $counter,
            'items' => $counter ? $this->getItems() : [],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getCounter()
    {
        return $this->createCounter($this->wishlistHelper->getItemCount());
    }

    /**
     * Create button label based on wishlist item quantity
     *
     * @param int $count
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase|null
     */
    protected function createCounter($count)
    {
        if ($count > 1) {
            return __('%1 items', $count);
        } elseif ($count == 1) {
            return __('1 item');
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get wishlist items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getItems()
    {
        $this->view->loadLayout();

        $collection = $this->wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection();
        $collection->clear()->setInStockFilter(true)->setOrder('added_at');

        $items = [];
        foreach ($collection as $wishlistItem) {
            $items[] = $this->getItemData($wishlistItem);
        }
        return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve wishlist item data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $wishlistItem
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getItemData(\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $wishlistItem)
    {
        $product = $wishlistItem->getProduct();
        return [
            'image' => $this->getImageData($product),
            'product_url' => $this->wishlistHelper->getProductUrl($wishlistItem),
            'product_name' => $product->getName(),
            'product_price' => $this->block->getProductPriceHtml(
                $product,
                'wishlist_configured_price',
                \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                ['item' => $wishlistItem]
            ),
            'product_is_saleable_and_visible' => $product->isSaleable() && $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_has_required_options' => $product->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($product),
            'add_to_cart_params' => $this->wishlistHelper->getAddToCartParams($wishlistItem, true),
            'delete_item_params' => $this->wishlistHelper->getRemoveParams($wishlistItem, true),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve product image data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function getImageData($product)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $helper */
        $helper = $this->imageHelperFactory->create()
            ->init($product, 'wishlist_sidebar_block');

        $template = $helper->getFrame()
            ? 'Magento_Catalog/product/image'
            : 'Magento_Catalog/product/image_with_borders';

        $imagesize = $helper->getResizedImageInfo();

        $width = $helper->getFrame()
            ? $helper->getWidth()
            : (!empty($imagesize[0]) ? $imagesize[0] : $helper->getWidth());

        $height = $helper->getFrame()
            ? $helper->getHeight()
            : (!empty($imagesize[1]) ? $imagesize[1] : $helper->getHeight());

        return [
            'template' => $template,
            'src' => $helper->getUrl(),
            'width' => $width,
            'height' => $height,
            'alt' => $helper->getLabel(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Clear cache.

**NB:** Only refresh is not enough for testing working or not. Add/Remove wishlist item then magento fire sidebar section data and load.

Comment: The sidebar is not visible.

Comment: Did you created 'VendorName\ModuleName' module and added my answer into your module?

Comment: Also clear browser cache, magento cache, add/remove wishilst item.

Comment: @SohelRana can u please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310131/magento2-display-configurable-product-price-range-on-wishlist-page

Answer (score 0):

Try This

> Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist

In line Number 20 Change

```
const SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER = 3;
```

TO

```
const SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER = 10;
```

Comment: @Waquar can u suggest me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310131/magento2-display-configurable-product-price-range-on-wishlist-page