# Magento2 display configurable product price range on wishlist page?

Tags: magento2, price, customer-account, wishlist

I would like to display the configurable product **Price Range**
[Min and Max] Ex: **$10.00 - $35.00** on wishlist items from the customer dashboard.
(Customer dashboard -> My wishlist items list & left sidebar).

Can you please advise how we can achieve this.
vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php

Here I am trying to overridden this method from custom module **vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist::getItemData()**

Here I have been facing two issues.

> 1. getting an issue with $itemResolver
> 2. Not fetching data from getPriceRange() method

app/code/Demo/PriceRange/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist" type="Demo\PriceRange\CustomerData\SidebarWishlistPriceRange"/> 
</config>
```

app/code/Sidebar/CustomerData/WishlistPriceRange.php

```
 <?php
 namespace Demo\PriceRange\CustomerData;
 use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
 use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data as PriceHelper;
 use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class SidebarWishlistPriceRange extends \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist
{

    /**
     * @var Configurable
     */
    protected $configurableProduct;

    /**
     * @var Configurable
     */
    protected $pricingHelper;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * SidebarWishlistPriceRange constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface|null $itemResolver
     * @param Configurable $configurableProduct
     * @param PriceHelper $pricingHelper
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface $itemResolver = null,
        Configurable $configurableProduct,
        PriceHelper $pricingHelper,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $wishlistHelper,
            $block,
            $imageHelperFactory,
            $view,
            $itemResolver
        );
        $this->configurableProduct = $configurableProduct;
        $this->pricingHelper = $pricingHelper;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $wishlistItem
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function getItemData(\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $wishlistItem)
    {
        try {
            $priceHtmlData = '';
            $product = $wishlistItem->getProduct();
            $priceHtmlData = $product->getTypeId() == Configurable::TYPE_CODE ? $this->getPriceRange($product) :
                $this->block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $product,
                    'wishlist_configured_price',
                    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                    ['item' => $wishlistItem]
                );
            return [
                //'image' => $this->getImageData($this->itemResolver->getFinalProduct($wishlistItem)), Here is the first issue - 1
                'product_sku' => $product->getSku(),
                'product_id' => $product->getId(),
                'product_url' => $this->wishlistHelper->getProductUrl($wishlistItem),
                'product_name' => $product->getName(),
                'product_price' => $priceHtmlData,
                'product_is_saleable_and_visible' => $product->isSaleable() && $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
                'product_has_required_options' => $product->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($product),
                'add_to_cart_params' => $this->wishlistHelper->getAddToCartParams($wishlistItem),
                'delete_item_params' => $this->wishlistHelper->getRemoveParams($wishlistItem),
            ];

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger('Something went wrong'.$e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $product
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPriceRange($product)
    {
        $childProductPrice = [];
        $childProducts = $this->configurableProduct->getUsedProducts($product);
        foreach ($childProducts as $child) {
            $price = number_format($child->getPrice(), 2, '.', '');
            $finalPrice = number_format($child->getFinalPrice(), 2, '.', '');
            $logger->info("finalPrice===".$finalPrice);
            if ($price == $finalPrice) {
                $childProductPrice[] = $price;
            } else if ($finalPrice < $price) {
                $childProductPrice[] = $finalPrice;
            }
        }
        $min = $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore(min($childProductPrice));
        $max = $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore(max($childProductPrice)); 
        if (min($childProductPrice) === max($childProductPrice)) {   
            return $this->getPriceRender($product, "$min", '');
        } else {           
            return $this->getPriceRender($product, "$min - $max", '');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $product
     * @param $price
     * @param string $text
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function getPriceRender($product, $price, $text='')
    {
        //Here is the second issue - 2
        return $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
            ->setTemplate('Demo_PriceRange::Wishlist/Sidebar/price_range.phtml')
            ->setData('price_id', 'product-price-'.$product->getId())
            ->setData('display_label', $text)
            ->setData('product_id', $product->getId())
            ->setData('display_value', $price)->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getImageData($product)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $helper */
        $helper = $this->imageHelperFactory->create()
            ->init($product, 'wishlist_sidebar_block');

        $template = 'Magento_Catalog/product/image_with_borders';

        try {
            $imagesize = $helper->getResizedImageInfo();
        } catch (NotLoadInfoImageException $exception) {
            $imagesize = [$helper->getWidth(), $helper->getHeight()];
        }

        $width = $helper->getFrame()
            ? $helper->getWidth()
            : $imagesize[0];

        $height = $helper->getFrame()
            ? $helper->getHeight()
            : $imagesize[1];

        return [
            'template' => $template,
            'src' => $helper->getUrl(),
            'width' => $width,
            'height' => $height,
            'alt' => $helper->getLabel(),
        ];
    }
}
```

app/code/Demo/PriceRange/view/frontend/templates/Wishlist/Sidebar/price_range.phtml

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<div class="price-box range second price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductId() ?>">
    <span class="special-price">
        <span class="price-container price-final_price">
            <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
                <span class="price-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayLabel(); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
                data-price-amount=""
                data-price-type="finalPrice1"
                class="price-wrapper">
                <span class="price"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayValue();?></span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

[image: wishlist page for configurable prodct]

Comment: Hello, You have to use plugin for display price. Please see this link, https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-change-product-price-with-plugin-magento-2.html  . Add conidtion on the logic, display price only if the page is wishilist.

Comment: @sunny actually this plugin will affect the entire add to cart functionality aswell. Can u suggest another solution for this

Comment: I think, you just want to display the price range on the wishlist page only. am i right?

Comment: Yes @SunnyRahevar correct for configurable products we need to display min & max price range on wishlist items. I have tried to find the exact file but no luck where it is rendering.

Comment: @NagarajuK - how did you change the main wishlist items ? can you please provide the solution that you used

Comment: @NagarajuK - check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332283/change-the-wishlist-item-collection-in-my-wish-list-tab-in-my-account-in-magen

Comment: @NagarajuK - i would really appreciate your help. I have been stuck with this issue since quite sometime

Comment: @ManashviBirla I will check your code on my local instance. update you thanks can u share the module.

Comment: @NagarajuK - i have shown my code here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332283/change-the-wishlist-item-collection-in-my-wish-list-tab-in-my-account-in-magen Do you need the entire module ?

Comment: How to get this wishlist list to custom file?

Answer (score 1):

You can Do this By Overriding `Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist`

Here is a Function Named as `getItemData()` which i actually responsible to render and pass data to section if you want to show price range change the login of

`Line 146`

```
'product_price' => $this->block->getProductPriceHtml(
                $product,
                'wishlist_configured_price',
                \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                ['item' => $wishlistItem]
            ),
```

Comment: thanks @WaqarAli it is responsible for sidebar wishlist items & what about main wishlist items? please refer to this screenshot https://prnt.sc/rxhmg3 for this can u help me where we have to do the implement logic?

Comment: i have updated my post can u plz help me on this