# change the wishlist item collection in "My Wish list" tab in My Account in Magento EE ver. 2.4.1

Tags: wishlist, magento2.4.1

I am using Magento EE ver. 2.4.1 and i want to override the wishlist item collection in my account. But i am facing the below issue :

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFinalProduct() on null in vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php

I have created the following preference in etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist" type="Vendor\Module\CustomerData\Wishlist" />

</config>
```

Vendor/Module/CustomerData/Wishlist.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\CustomerData;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image\NotLoadInfoImageException;
use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Wishlist extends \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist
{
     /**
     * @var string
     */
    const SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER = 3;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $wishlistHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
     */
    protected $imageHelperFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface
     */
    protected $view;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar
     */
    protected $block;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface
     */
    private $itemResolver;
    protected $wishlistFactory;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper
     * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface|null $itemResolver
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Sidebar $block,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $imageHelperFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory
    ) {
        $this->wishlistHelper = $wishlistHelper;
        $this->imageHelperFactory = $imageHelperFactory;
        $this->block = $block;
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Get wishlist items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getItems()
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/mbPref2.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("here");

        $this->view->loadLayout();
        
        $wishlist = $this->wishlistFactory->create()->load(162);
        
        // i have used this custom collection instead of the default item collection
        $collection = $wishlist->getItemCollection();
        
        //$collection = $this->wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection();

        //show all wishlist items
        $collection->clear()->setInStockFilter(true)->setOrder('added_at');

        $logger->info(get_class($collection));
        
        $items = [];
        foreach ($collection as $wishlistItem) {
            $items[] = $this->getItemData($wishlistItem);
        }
        return $items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to override the full file not only the specific function. Then check working or not.

Comment: @AmitSaini - i resolved that error, but the wishlist item collection doesnt change. Any idea ?